# How would an expression like B.3/34 be pronounced, in historic or recent UK speech?

Tags: punctuation, pronunciation, british-english

The expression is [a designation for a 1930's British bomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_Whitworth_Whitley), but the question really focuses on the ".". Would a UK speaker in the 1930's, or late 20th century, or now, say "bee *full stop* three stroke thirty-four"? A North American speaker (within my lifetime, which does not extend to the '30s) would probably say "period", or more recently, "dot". A few trained in radio procedures might say "decimal" (and "three-four"). But "full stop" is uniquely non-North American usage and I've got no calibration for whether there were alternatives in some situations, or how it might vary regionally or by education.

A North American would would probably say "slash" for the oblique character; to my understanding, a UK speaker would say "stroke" (at least where it was a delimiter and not the currency symbol). Is that also a valid assumption?

Comment: In modern times BrE does sometimes use "period" (borrowed from AmE) but perhaps not often in 1930. We might say *point* as if that designation were a decimal, though. For the stroke/slash, they might not have said anything at all, for example "B three thirty-four".

Comment: No, a full stop in BrE occurs at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @WeatherVane a "full stop" occurs at the end of a sentence I agree. However I think British people in the '30s might well have used the word "stop" with which they would have been familiar from telegram conventions. That sort of construction was so uncommon then that I can't remember any use of it in normal conversation in the 50s and 60s.

Comment: As another link from the question's link, to [List of Air Ministry specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Air_Ministry_specifications) explains, **B.3/34** wasn't a name but a *classification* so its pronunciation at that time may not be easy to establish. Perhaps it was pronounced like the [Dewey Decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Decimal_Classification) classifications, and a librarian could throw some light on it.

Comment: @BoldBen - people wrote 'B.B.C.' in the 1930s (and up to the 50s or 60s) but I don't think anyone said "bee stop bee stop see stop' in conversation. They might when giving dictation.

Comment: My mother, who worked in an ops room, was given a ride over Germany at the end of the war in what she called a **B3**. "Stop" was used as others have described: in telegrams and  dictation. Dewey Decimal wasn't then widely known in the UK. I think my parents used "stroke" or, if they wanted to be more formal or officious, "**oblique**". "B three oblique three four" or "B three stroke three four" both sound right to me, though in a conversation about these planes they'd probably lapse into Weather Vane's "B three thirty-four". I don't think they'd have used "slash".

Comment: As a retired librarian, I think _point_ more likely than _stop_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's true but B.B.C was very definitely a set of initials in the same way as my initials would be B.B and yours M.H. The difference with the plane designation is that the character following the B. is a number. I suppose B. might have been short for 'Bomber' in which case it would have been an intitial and the dot ignored as you say.

Comment: @KateBunting As something of a mathemetician I'm aware that a decimal point is supposed to be half a characted up from the line on which the numbers appear. However I don't think that it was available on mechanical typewriters (it's a bit awkward to type on a computer to be honest) but I suspect that engineers might have been a bit reluctant to refer to a 'dot', 'full stop" or "stop" as a point. We really need someone who was around at the time but there are very few of them left!

Comment: I'm thinking BoldBen's hit the nail on the head: this semi-formulaic kind of notation was niche and novel, and the in-crowd probably had an idiom for it, perhaps very localized. One can imagine the Navy and the Air Force having different customs. Having said that, @Kate Bunting's reference to "point" is very likely the most probable, if it's known to have been used in other contexts.